# Testing Angular Lazy Loaded

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, lazy-loading, testbed

There are a lot of old answers that exist on this platform and I have tried them all, but none of them resolved my request.

Some methods were deprecated, and I found info that requires to use of `NgModule` instead of `SpyNgModuleFactoryLoader`. I also watched this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcwFcBsTAtM`

But whatever I did, it didn't work. Has anyone tried testing lazy-loaded routes these days?

`app-routing.module.spec.ts`

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from './pages/home/home.module';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pages/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'sample',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/pages/sample/sample.module').then((m) => m.SampleModule),
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

describe('Router: App', () => {
  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    router.initialNavigation();
  });

  it('should navigate to files', fakeAsync(() => {
    const loader = TestBed.inject(NgModule);
    loader.stubbedModules = {
      './pages/home/home.module#HomeModule': HomeModule,
    };
    router.resetConfig([{ path: 'home', loadChildren: (): any => import('./pages/home/home.module').then((mod) => mod.HomeModule) }]);
    router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    tick(50);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(location.path()).toBe('/home');
  }));
});
```

This code gives me bellow error:

```bash
Chrome Headless 103.0.5060.114 (Mac OS 10.15.7) Router: App should navigate to files FAILED
        NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[DecoratorFactory -> DecoratorFactory]: 
          NullInjectorError: No provider for DecoratorFactory!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'DecoratorFactory', 'DecoratorFactory' ] })
            at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:49234:21)
```

I tried to test angular application with lazy loaded routing, but it is not worked

Comment: At first glance it looks to me that you should `await` the `compileComponents` call: `beforeEach(async () => { await TestBed.... });`

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar/src/navbar-item/navbar-item.component.spec.ts#L16) of using the `RouterTestingModule`, however I wouldn't see the benefit of trying lazy-loaded pages in unit tests...

Comment: Thanks @Pieterjan for your support. But, I could not see any redirection here. I think you created a "BsNavbarItemTestComponent" contains the given links. I need to check the url location is correct when redirected to a page. Does the url path redirect to "/a", as when clicking "<a [routerLink]='["/a"]'>a</a>"?